# How to compile libwebsockets for MQTT (mosquitto broker) in windows Machine?

Tags: javascript, windows, mqtt, mosquitto, libwebsockets

I am working in a Hybrid App development. I would like to implement MQTT service in my app. I heard JavaScript supports only websocket protocol to communicate with MQTT broker. For that libwebsocket is required, But, I couldn't get any explanation for "how to compile libwebsockets for MQTT in my windows 7 machine".
Can you explain in detail step by step way to install MQTT with libwebsocket in windows machine.